# Which expression is equivalent?

Tags: expression

This is for a study guide by the way:
I would appreciate the help. I tried using De Morgan's Laws but I don't think it applies here. I am new to CS1 and trying to understand which relates.

10. Consider the following expression:  (A > B) && (C <= B)

    Assume that A, B, and C are integer variables.  Which of the expressions given below is (are) equivalent to the one given above?

    ```
    I.  !(A < B) && !(C >= B)
    II. (A > B) && (B > C)
    III.    !((A <= B) || (B < C))
    ```

Comment: Why don't you try various integers to gain insight?

Comment: Thanks for your comment !I tried to make A = 2, B=1 , C=1 but all of them don't match up to the original expression because for I. I get !(2<1) && !(1>=1) does that mean it's not allowed?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first is not good because `A > B` is not same to `!(A < B)` (`!(A <= B)` should be, you can try 3 and 3 for `A` and `B` to check it).
Second is not good, as `(C <= B)` is not same to `(B > C)` (`(B >= C)` should be, try again 3 and 3 as values).
The third one can be converted to `!(A <= B) && !(B < C)`.
`!(A <= B)` is equal to `A > B`;
and `!(B < C)` we can convert into `B >= C` or `C <= B`, it's equal.

So, third answer is good.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I really appreciate it. When I compiled it 3 was the only one that worked but I didn't know if 3 was equal to the original.

Comment: It is ;) If it helped you, please mark an answer as correct. You can also upvote it, if you wish.

Comment: I definitely will and once I get more reputation I will upvote you!